# ASP.NET Core application responds with 503 Service Unavailable on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, asp.net

I have a stock, nearly unmodified Visual Studio template ASP.NET Core application I am trying to run on Ubuntu 18.04. I've followed this guide: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

After a while of hitting and missing I managed to make ASP.NET service run. However when I visit my page I'm seeing a 503 Service Unavailable error.

My Apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect / https://example.com
        Redirect /panel https://example.com/panel
        Redirect /privacy https://example.com/privacy
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com

        RewriteEngine On
        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite"
        LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6

        # ASP.NET application
        # launchSettings.json is configured to listen on this port
        ProxyPass /panel https://localhost:33138/
        ProxyPassReverse /panel https://localhost:33138/

        ProxyPass /api/socket ws://localhost:44909/api/socket
        ProxyPassReverse /api/socket ws://localhost:44909/api/socket

        ProxyPass /pgadmin4 !
        ProxyPass /privacy !
        ProxyPass /contact !
        ProxyPass /panel !

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:44909/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:44909/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLOptions +StrictRequire
        SSLProtocol TLSv1
        ServerAlias example.com
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This is the result of `systemctl status tpanel` (my ASP daemon):

```
● tpanel.service - a .NET Core 3.1 server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tpanel.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-12-13 10:16:21 CET; 4h 1min ago
 Main PID: 2765 (dotnet)
    Tasks: 16 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tpanel.service
           └─2765 /usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/TPanel/publish/TPanel.dll

Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]:       Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]:       Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]:       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]:       Hosting environment: Production
Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]:       Content root path: /var/www/TPanel/publish
```

`launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50015",
      "sslPort": 44313
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "TPanel": {
      "commandName": "TPanel",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:33138"
    }
  }
}
```

But like I said, when I go to `example.com/panel` I see 503 error. Other parts of my website work well.

Other info:

- I have another unrelated application running that made use of 5001 port, I replaced it with something else though so it shouldn't be a problem
- It doesn't seem to matter whether I set the port of my application to `33138` or `5001`, it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`launchSettings.json` is a VS Code thing. It doesn’t do anything here.

Your application is running in ports 5000 (HTTP) and 5001 (HTTPS), that is an undeniable fact we can see in the log:

> ```
> Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]:       Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
> Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Dec 13 10:16:22 vps-example dotnet[2765]:       Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
> ```

Apache is configured to connect to the application on port 33138:

> ```
>     ProxyPass /panel https://localhost:33138/
>     ProxyPassReverse /panel https://localhost:33138/
> ```

The application does not listen on that port, hence 503 – sent by Apache, not ASP.NET Core.

Fix your application’s listen port. For example, in `appsettings.json` or via `ASPNETCORE_URLS`. More information is available [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration).

By the way, you have a mismatch in trailing slashes in `ProxyPass`. That could cause additional problems.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I really should have paid attention more. I will try it